# How do I add/modify text in the email results sent on CruiseControl.NET task completion?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

It is not obvious to me where/how to configure the text that gets sent out in the emails after a build is complete/fails.  I am getting emails, but there are some details I need to add.  Where is that/how is that done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First hit in google: ["Modifiy Emails sent by CruiseControl.NET"](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/ModifyingEmailsSentUsingCruiseControlNETsEmailPublisher.aspx)

Comment: I thought perhaps there was an easier way to do it. The content I want to add is FIXED content. Having to screw around with xml and xsl seems like overkill for a simple couple lines of fixed content

Comment: I agree. That mechanism was not necessarily a great one. I think you can disable the sending of email, and use a task to actually send the email yourself.

Comment: actually modifying the XSL is all you would need to do for a few static lines, and it is just as easy to put there as anywhere else. This is a simple 30 second task.

Comment: That is now a dead link, your response is a good example of an unhelpful answer on StackOverflow.